# SharePoint 2007 - Calendar time column freeze pane

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I built a basic schedule for my team on our team site *SharePoint 2007* and I am noticing a formatting issue. When we scroll the schedule to the right, you can no longer see the time column to the left. I was hoping there might be a simple way to resolve this issue and "freeze pane" the time column. I do not have access to add a content editor web part, but I do have access to SharePoint designer. So please keep that restriction in mind.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: So in your free time, you go through peoples posts and remove anything that looks like they are being polite instead of assisting ? Man, you are cool.

Comment: Did you read the link? Yes, I spend time improving this site.